# Why can null be written with a backslash?

Tags: php, null, namespaces, constants

In all PHP manuals, it says that `null`, `true`, and `false` are internal values. However, nowhere does it say why they can be written with backslash: `\null`, `\false`, `\true`.

What exactly are `null`, `false`, and `true` in PHP?

A constant or are they some hack for the interpreter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null`, `false` and `true` are defined in PHP as constants. The backslash means [global namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php), so you can just specify the full namespace for these constants like this: `\null`. This is not necessary, because all constants are global (apart from the ones defined using `const`).

> Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope. For more information on scope, read the manual section on variable scope. - [PHP Manual on Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

Functions and constants do not need to have fully qualified name. This is in contrast to [classes which must be specified with their namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php) e.g. `\Exception`.

> For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions or constants if a namespaced function or constant does not exist. - [PHP Manual on namespace fallback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

## EDIT

`null`, `false` and `true` are very special constants in PHP. They are the only ones which are still explicitly *"case-insensitive"*. The reason why I put it in quotes is because the actual constant name is defined as `NULL`, `FALSE`, `TRUE`, except... it actually isn't. It is lower-cased:

```
define('TRUE', 'foo'); // works
define('True', 'bar'); // works too, even in combination with the first one
define('true', 'abc'); // Notice: Constant true already defined

var_dump(constant('TRUE')); // string 'foo'
var_dump(constant('True')); // string 'bar'
var_dump(constant('true')); // boolean true
```

If you remove the `define()`-s then all constants will point back to the boolean even if you use `constant('True')`. - https://ideone.com/CZSwiX

PHP manual states:

> To specify a boolean literal, use the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.

You might ask yourself then, what is the value of these constants? If you execute `var_dump(TRUE);` the result will be `bool(true)`, and if you do `echo true;` it will print out `1`. What are they defined as in the PHP source code? [Here is the answer](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_constants.c#L136):

```
REGISTER_MAIN_BOOL_CONSTANT("TRUE", 1, CONST_PERSISTENT);
REGISTER_MAIN_BOOL_CONSTANT("FALSE", 0, CONST_PERSISTENT);
REGISTER_MAIN_NULL_CONSTANT("NULL", CONST_PERSISTENT);
```

What is more interesting is that they are really treated as [special constants](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_constants.c#L238) and cannot be redefined by the user (other predefined constants can be redefined in their own namespace with `const`). I would therefore argue that for all intents and purposes you can treat these 3 as not just constants, but special values akin to reserved keywords. For the moment they are still implemented as a case-insensitive hack in PHP, but as the comment in the [commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/3d39479f4d7c86c66aa92fc5d0d97fb660109ee9) by @NikiC states: *"In the future we may convert them from constants to reserved keywords."*

Interesting fact: Until PHP 7 `true`, `false` and `null` were not reserved keywords, so you could [try something like this](https://3v4l.org/3VPfg):

```PHP
class TRUE {
    const int = 'This is the truest of the integers';
}
var_dump(TRUE::int);
```

**tl;dr:**
Accessing the `\null`, `\false` and `\true` works, because they are internally defined as special-constants and all constants in PHP are in the global namespace.

Answer (score 4):

[`null`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php), [`true`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), and [`false`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) are all constants as defined by the documentation:

> There is only one value of type null, and that is the case-insensitive constant NULL.

and

> To specify a boolean literal, use the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.

When you put `\` before them, it forces PHP to look in the global namespace.

In the same light, you could test this by defining your own constants:

```
define('TEST', 'true');

var_dump(\TEST); // string(4) "true"
```

Another example of namespaced constants:

```
namespace Test {
  const A = 'A';
}

namespace { // Global namespace
  const A = 'B';

  echo A . PHP_EOL; // B
  echo Test\A . PHP_EOL; // A
}
```

If you take a look in [`get_defined_constants`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) with the categorized argument set to `true`, you'll see `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `NULL` defined in `Core`.

Comment: Are there any reasons for setting backslashes to up performance?

Comment: @KartAv1k I've never come across anything that states either way if I'm honest except the other answer in this question which doesn't seem to cite anything or explain *how*.